# preventing users from navigating to some urls after login - angular-ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

currently i'm developing a sample admin application using angularjs, in my application. i have  used **ui-router** instead of **ngRoute** to define the urls. on my config function states are defined as below.

```
sampleModule.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');
    $stateProvider
        .state('login',{
            url:'/login',
            templateUrl: 'views/html/login.html',
            controller: 'authCtrl'
        }).state('main', {
            url:'/main',
            templateUrl: 'views/html/main.html',
            controller: 'adminViewCtrl'
        });
}]);
```

in the run state of the application i'm redirecting the users to their respective view as follows.

```
sampleModule.run(function ($rootScope, AuthService, $state) {

    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event) {
            if (AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go('main');
            } else {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go('login');
            }
    });
});
```

but the problem i'm facing is application giving following exception and crashes some times when URL changes.

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I put a debug point to   ***run***   function of the application and 
and noticed that error coming because content inside   ***if (AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {***   condition executing in a infinite loop.

below is the image for the errors in chrome developer tools

[image: chrome developer tools errors]

i'm confused about the things happening here, i Googled for few hours and was not able to come up with a straight answer, i even tried putting ***event.preventDefault()***  as some suggestions i saw , but it didn't helped to resolve the problem.

i'm wondering what error i'm doing here? is there any better way to restrict user access to the log-in page,or some other parts of the application after logging in to the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are constantly redirecting user to same state. Here is what happens: user goes to some state, `$stateChangeStart` is triggered, you redirect user again to some other state, and again `$stateChangeStart` is triggered, you check authentication and redirect again, and that continues until `RangeError` appears. What you should probably do is only redirect user when he is unauthorized, if he is authorized, let him see the page he is looking for.

```
sampleModule.run(function ($rootScope, AuthService, $state) {

    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState) {
            if (!AuthService.isAuthenticated() && toState.name !== 'login') {
                $state.go('login');
            } else if(AuthService.isAuthenticated() && toState.name === 'login') {
                $state.go('main');
            } 
    });
});
```

Here you check if user is authorized and if navigation state is not login (since he already got redirected) and later check if it's login page he is wanting for and redirecting to `main`

Comment: @ domakas - thank you very much for the quick answer, it helped to resolve my problem :)